# Google Drive vs Google Docs in doc conversion

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

I've noticed that downloading a shared file from Google Docs allows you to convert it to another file format, but not when from Google Drive. Is it possible to do the same from Google Drive as well?

When the document is on drive
`https://drive.google.com/file/d/FILEID/view?usp=sharing`

will download as pdf, but cannot be converted to any other format when using direct url
`https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILE_ID`
Is there a means to convert it to another type, like a doc?

When the document is on google docs
 `https://docs.google.com/document/d/FILE_ID/edit?usp=sharing`
you can download it into any format
 `https://docs.google.com/document/d/FILE_ID/export?format=doc` (or pdf, etc)

Comment: Welcome. As per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well -. ([Why vote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)?)

Answer (score 1):

**It is not possible**.

Simply because it is a different application. Google Docs is a text application so it is programmed to be able to convert to other text formats while Google drive is a storage application.

Similarly, Microsoft Word can convert to other text formats (or Photoshop can convert from .jpg to .png) while Windows cannot.